# Getting value from splunk search result to Email Alert Message

Tags: email, alert, splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

Im trying to get values from a splunk search into an email alert Message. My splunk search query used to trigger an alert is `"resourceGroup="myResourceGroup" severity="Error"` (simplified version). The output of the search looks like this

```
   {
   msg: Error encountered will getting details from API 
   resourceGroup: myResourceGroup
   severity: Error
   sourceContext: SystemContext
   success: false
  }
```

Q1: How do i get the `msg` value from the search result in my email alert? Below is a screen shot of splunk Alert Email Message Box?

Q2: Say i wanted to send `msg` and `sourceContext`, is there a way to insert ONLY these fields into a custom table?

.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to extract the fields you want to use in the alert.  A simple way to do that (if not already done) is with `rex`.

```
resourceGroup="myResourceGroup" severity="Error"
| rex "msg: (?<msg>[^\n}+)"
| rex "sourceContext: (?<sourceContext>\S+)"
```

Then reference the fields within `$` in the alert message.

```
Msg = $msg$
sourceContext = $sourceContext$
```